# Python append multiple values to nested dictionary by key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add another value to a nested dictionary by key, I have the below code but it doesn't work properly

```
Content is a file with:
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d

dict   = {}

for line in content:
    values = line.split(",")
    a = str.strip(values[0])
    b = str.strip(values[1])
    c = str.strip(values[2])
    d = str.strip(values[3])

    if a not in dict:
        dict.update({a: {'Value1': b, 'Value2': c, 'Value3': d}},)
    else:
       dict[a]['Value1'].update(b)
```

I want it to look like:

```
a {'Value1': 'b,b,b', 'Value2': 'c', 'Value3': 'd'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the content of ``content`` to your question.

Comment: Not a big deal, but you can probably write `a, b, c, d = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]` so it looks more pythonic :)

Comment: @Ding `.split(',')`*

Comment: I've added content if it helps. I'll make changes to split as well

Comment: Try

    `dict[a]['Value1'] += b`

Comment: edited so its b,b,b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}

for line in content: 
  values = line.split(",")
  a = str.strip(values[0])
  b = str.strip(values[1])
  c = str.strip(values[2])
  d = str.strip(values[3])

  if a not in dictionary.keys():
      dictionary = {a: {'Value1': b, 'Value2': c, 'Value3': d}} # creates dictionary
  else:
      dictionary[a]['Value1'] += ','+b # accesses desired value and updates it with ",b"
print(dictionary)
#Output: {'a': {'Value1': 'b,b,b', 'Value2': 'c', 'Value3': 'd'}}
```

This should do your trick. You gotta add the ',' in the else statement because you removed it when you used `split(',')`

Answer (score 2):

You don't quite understand with `update` does; it's [replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), not appending.  Try this, instead:

```
if a not in dict:
    dict.update({a: {'Value1': b, 'Value2': c, 'Value3': d}},)
else:
   dict[a]['Value1'] += ',' + b
```

Output:

```
a {'Value3': 'd', 'Value2': 'c', 'Value1': 'b,b,b'}
```

If you want to preserve the order of the `Value` sub-fields, then use an `OrderedDict`.