# How to append multiple key and value into a nested dictionary using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have looked through few questions regarding nested dictionary such as [link_a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831228/how-to-append-multiple-lists-to-a-nested-dictionary), [link_b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944706/how-to-create-nested-dictionary-in-python-with-3-lists), and [link_c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593653/python-append-multiple-values-to-nested-dictionary-by-key). But i cant seem to find the solution (or i couldnt figure it out).
So i already have a dictionary which is in this format:`{'key_01': ['value1', 'value2'], key_02: ....}` which goes until key_08 where certain keys have different amount of 'value' in them.

For each value1 and value2 has 2 more additional values which are `x` and `y` in which i will obtain once i run my program.

So the final output that i want it as below:

```
{'key_01': 
   ['value1' : 
     ['x': 2], 
     ['y': 3]], 
   ['value2': 
     ['x': 2], 
     ['y': 3]], ....}
```

This is one of the method i tried by using this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-dictionary/#:%7E:text=Adding%20elements%20to%20a%20Nested%20Dictionary&text=One%20way%20to%20add%20a,%27key%27%3A%20%27value%27%7D%20.)  for adding into dictionary:

```
x = 5
for i in range(len(demo_dict['key_01'])):
    for val in demo_dict['key_01']:
        demo_dict['key_01'][0] = x
```

But it changed the value1 to 5 which is not what i want. And i know i cannot use append. Now im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need

```
data = {'key_01': ['value1', 'value2'], key_02: ....} 
result = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    for i in v:
        result.setdefault(k, {}).update({'v': {'x': x, 'y': y}})
```

**Output:**

```
{'key_01': {
    'v': {
        'x': x, 
        'y': y
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every pair of 'key':value should be in a dictionary, like:

```
dict = {'key_01':[
          {'value1':{'x': 2,'y': 3}, 
           'value2':{'x': 2,'y': 3}, 
           'value3': ....]}
```

So key_01 has a list of dictionaries value1,value2,value3, where each has a dictionary for x and y.

this way you can access the 'x' and 'y' values as

```
dict['value_01']['value1']['x'] and dict['value_01']['value1']['x']
```

Comment: Ive made a little research regarding dict in a dict and seems like i got the format that i want. but it seems to not append the second value (value2). i'll share my code in the update.